# How to find a string with specified length in a text file using findstr or grep command?

Tags: grep, findstr

I want to find a string of length 8 which starts with the characters "alo", in a text file.

For findstr, I have tried the following command - **`findstr /R "\<alo" file.txt`**. This command searches for strings starting with "alo" but cannot search for strings of length 8. For grep, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: By "string", do you mean a line or a word?

Comment: Consider the following examples - Eg - alo44531, alogto99, etc

Comment: Are those meant to be examples of lines or words?

Comment: They are words.

Comment: Then I'd try `grep -E '\<alo\w{5}\>'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -woE  'alo.{5}' filename
```

-o is for printing only the match

-E is to use extended regex

-w will make the given expression match only whole words

The number inside the parenthesis specifies the number of character to match after the letters 'alo'

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -E '^alo(.*){5}$' filename
```